# Fitting upper and lower envelope in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, data-fitting

I need to make a fit of the upper envelope (that is, the curve passing through the maximas) of the following graph: [image]

Is there a way to do it in gnuplot?

Comment: No, you can't do this with gnuplot, its a plotting program and not designed for general numerical problems.

Comment: This is an interesting problem.  If you could isolate the set of points that form the boundary for the maximas, then you could fit that using gnuplot.  Unfortunately, gnuplot won't find the "envelope" for you...

Comment: @mgilson in practice, I've solved it “by hand”, i.e. I used excel to erase all points which y coordinate is less of one of the previous (this gives an increasing sequence). I'm still curious if there's a more smart way to solve this kind of problem, though.